# How to get the font size in HTML?

Tags: html, jquery

I wanted to make a word processor that also has the font size feature.
The problem is, when I test it, it never changes the font size.

```js
function size() {
    console.log("Font size changed");
    let fontSize = document.getElementById("fontsizeInput");
    document.getElementById("editor").style.fontSize = document.getElementById("fontsizeInput");
};
```

```html
               <input type="text" id="fontsizeInput" class="fontinput" style="width: 33px;" maxlength="3">
               <button class="btn" id="sizeOK" onclick="size()"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
```

Comment: bro you need to try ck editor that will give you functionality like this

Comment: Hi you need to use `.value` i.e : `document.getElementById("fontsizeInput").value+ 'px'` when you assign new font-size to editor div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("editor").style.fontSize = document.getElementById("fontsizeInput").value+"px"
```

Use .value & add "px" after that